# Straight line $y = x + 2$ cuts circle at $x^{2} + y^{2} = 20$ at $A$ and $B$ determine the values of $A$ and $B$

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

Im currently studying circles so now that I have two equations I'm confused. I'm asked to determine the values of $A$ and $B$ given straight line $y = x+2$ that cuts circle at $x^{2} + y^{2} = 20$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Could you tell us what you mean by $A$ and $B$? They are the points of intersection of the line $y = x + 2$ and the circle $x^{2}  + y^{2} = 20$?

Answer (score 1):

If $(x,y)$ is in the intersection of the line $y=x+2$ and the circle $x^2+y^2=20$, then\begin{align*}x^2+(x+2)^2 & =20 \\
x^2+x^2+4x+4 & =20 \\
2x^2+4x-16 & =0 \\
x^2+2x-8 & =0 \\
(x-2)(x+4) & =0
\end{align*}hence $x=2$ or $x=-4$. This gives the points $(2,4)$ and $(-4,-2)$, because $y=x+2$.

Comment: This is correct, but I wish you hadn't posted it so quickly. I'm glad you want to help, but when the OP shows no effort of their own answering their question, you should comment asking for that work before answering yourself. (I note that you have quickly answered some other questions too.)

Comment: What's the problem? It's great to see a quick response, sometimes you can't even start a math problem, I know how it feels. We've all been there...

Comment: It's a clear answer on a short exercise that will help the OP to move on with his problem set.